# Disable nvidia card in notebook

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, nvidia-settings

I have a notebook with both Intel and nvidia graphics. I activated Intel instead nvidia in nvidia-settings. But I still can hear fan working.

How to disable videocard completely?

Comment: The fan cools the cpu and graphics, fan operation is normal.